# How to bundle DLLs and OCXs together

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have written a 'peak' dll that relies on 8 other DLLs. These other 8 DLLs in turn rely on dozens of other DLLs and registered OCXs.

If I copy all of these into the output of a build, it all works OK.

What I want to do now tho is copy all of that into a Program Files (x86)\myDll folder and use it there for multiple installed applications that all want to use that peak DLL without each having to have a copy of all of those files in their own install folders.

Let's say I have installed the peak dll and all of its support files in the Programs Files (x86) folder on my build machine.  I would like to start a new VS project that has the peak dll as a reference and then be able to compile and run without copying the peak dll and its support files to the build output (or the apps install folder later on).

I tried it the obvious way (referencing the peak dll in its 'permanent' folder) but 'Could not find file or assembly xxxx or one of its dependencies.'

What is the right way to do this?

Dave

Comment: are you talking your build environment or the deployed application environment. You should just be able create a project reference to the project that builds your peak.dll.

Comment: Neither .NET nor Windows will let you easily create DLL Hell like this.  The .NET assemblies should go in the GAC, the OCXs can stay put, any native support DLL needs to be found with SetDllDirectory() or the PATH.  You can use AppDomain.AssemblyResolve when you like it hot.  You *will* regret this deeply some day.